# How to display a manipulated model content in QAbstractItemView

Tags: qt, model-view

I have a `QSqlTableModel` and a `QTableView` displaying the contents of the model.

I've managed to customize the editing of models subclassing `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplementing the methods `setEditorData`, `setModelData` and `updateEditorGeometry`.

What do I need to do now is put in the view a text based on the original model. Let me give a toy example:

Suppose I have stored the value `"10"` in the model. What I want is to display a manipulated version of this value in the view, for example `"10 kg"`, but without changing the actual content of the model.

(This was only a simplified example, the real problem is not just putting a suffix.)

How can I do this?
I could not find the answer in the documentation and looking at the [two](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-stardelegate.html) [examples](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-stardelegate.html) I could find similar to my problem, but they deal with new representation, drawn as stars (for example). What I want is simpler: I want to be able to rewrite the string.

Sorry about the crap english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find an answer.

The truth is that the answer was in the documentation and I let it go unnoticed. Just reimplement the method [`displayText`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText) of `QStyledItemDelegate`.

[Here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp#line272) is the original implementation. It was good to see it to get an idea of how to do the modifications.

To do more complex manipulations, it is also good to take a look at the method [`initStyleOption`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) ([implementation](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp#line320)).

Comment: Thanks, getting rid of displayed text was my major headache and this solved it.